# Track session time with Heap

Tags: session, heap, metrics

I have a website and would be good if we could track the average session time within a certain page. This metric is relevant because each subset of pages has different content and we need to track the time spent at each page.

The relevant metrics:
- average session time
- average number of sessions by day

I read the heap documentation and I didn't find a clear way to do this. Also, I didn't find something telling that this is impossible.

Any help will be good.